# What lock can secure a 4th generation Time Capsule from theft?

Tags: security, time-capsule

The 4th generation Time Capsule has a [**security slot** at the far right of the back panel](https://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/0/MA428/en_US/TimeCapsule_SetupGuide.pdf#page=8):

[image]

However, the manual does not mention **what kind of lock** I can attach to it.

**What locks are compatible?** For instance, does the [Kensington MicroSaver](http://store.apple.com/ca_k12nonbts_5005430/product/H0903LL/A/kensington-microsaver-ds-keyed-lock-for-ultra-thin-notebooks) work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, that's a Kensington slot and the product you linked will work and is on the high end in price and fit/finish. Anything compatible will work - you can open http://amazon.com and then search for "kensington type laptop lock" for dozens of vendors at various price points and key/cable configurations.

Comment: Do they have different sizes? And how can I know if it's compatible (for instance, my laptop seems to have a slightly larger hole).

Comment: @RubenVerborgh I've added a search term and confirmed your choice would work. Keep in mind, that if someone grabbed and pulled the Time Capsule, the plastic would likely break. What this slot does is make the resale value of the device much less. You can't take it to a Pawn Shop or such and say it's not stolen as easily. I'd encrypt the data on the device if that's your concern and/or put it in a metal cage if you don't want it moving. Kensington type cables deter casual pranks and people looking for a quick $$ to sell something that looks fit.

Answer (score 4):

The slot is a standard Kensington compatible lock style slot, or t-bar lock. All [Kensington Locks](http://www.kensington.com/us/us/4482/locks) will work with this slot, including the Microsaver line.

Kensington offers a [smaller lock](http://www.kensington.com/us/us/6437/kensington-security-slot-mini-slot-clicksafe%C2%AE-anchor-integration-resources#.VSZ1nvnF92s) as well, reserved for tablets and ultrabooks, whose slot is less than 12mm. This uses a different attachment mechanism, but whose mechanism (Cleat) is backwardly compatible with the original slot.